# Passing child class objects to std::function parameter

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, stl

I have the following message class psuedo-code (third-party, cannot be changed).

**messages.h**:

```
class AbstractMessage {
    // pure virtual
};

class MessageA : public AbstractMessage {
    // implements everything
    const static std::string messageName = "MessageA";
};

class MessageB : public AbstractMessage {
    // implements everything
    const static std::string messageName = "MessageB";
};
```

In my application code, I am attempting to write a function to register an external function to handle any message:

**application.cpp**:

```
bool register_handler(std::string messageType, std::function<void(AbstractMessage&)>messageHandler) {
    // add the string and function to a map to be called
}
```

However, I need to be able to pass in MessageA or MessageB functions. For example:

**main.cpp**:

```
void processMessageA(MessageA &msg) {
    // do something
}

Application myApp;
```

This becomes problematic when I attempt to do the following:

```
std::function<void(MessageA&)> f(processMessageA);
myApp.register_handler("MessageA", f);
```

MessageA should be a valid AbstractMessage via inheritance, but I get the following error:

`'Error    C2664:  'bool Application::register_handler(std::string,const std::function<void (AbstractMessage &)> &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::function<void(MessageA &)>' to 'const std::function<void (AbstractMessage &)> &`

Is this possible in C++? In Java I would use a functional interface, and pass any valid method via `this::`. Inheritance would validate the method parameters.

Comment: Let's say you manage to cast your `void(MessageA&)` to a `void(AbstractMessage&)`. What happens when you pass in a `MessageB` to that function?

Comment: @super I‘m following. What would be the alternative or best practice for generic message handler mapping? I tried using a template, but had issues using it as a map key to determine which handler to call.

Comment: A better design would not need to know the exact type, the interface (`AbstractMessage&`) should be enough. But if you third party code is preventing that, casting is your only option AFAIK.

Comment: @super Now I’m not following, my current scenario is I have the interface AbstractMessage&.